# Can Process B (with eid) Interact with an Enclave after Process A Has Established a Connection?

Tags: security, process, sdk, enclave

I'm working with enclave technology and have encountered a specific scenario I need clarification on. Suppose a process, let's call it Process A, establishes a connection with an enclave. My question revolves around the potential interaction of another process, Process B, with the same enclave. *Given that Process B has the appropriate enclave identifier (eid), is it possible for it to interact with or call the enclave after Process A's connection?*

Furthermore, if I want to conduct an experiment or verification regarding this, which example in the SampleCode should I consider modifying? I'm looking for guidance on the appropriate starting point to experiment with this scenario.[SampleCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5y88S.jpg)

**Reference to Sample Code:**
For my experiments and the context of my question, I am referring to the SampleCode available in the Intel SGX SDK, specifically the examples provided at [GitHub - Intel SGX SampleCode](https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx/tree/master/SampleCode). I am looking into these examples to understand how to modify them for testing interactions between multiple processes and an enclave.

So far, I have experimented with basic enclave setups and interactions following the standard SampleCode provided in the SDK. My initial trials involved establishing a connection with the enclave using a single process (Process A). These experiments went as expected, with Process A successfully communicating with the enclave.

However, I have not yet attempted to introduce a second process (Process B) into this setup. My expectation is that Process B, equipped with the correct enclave identifier (eid), should theoretically be able to interact with the enclave even after Process A has established a connection. I'm uncertain, though, about whether this is feasible given the enclave's security protocols and operational mechanisms.

I'm seeking guidance on this specific aspect and any modifications that might be necessary in the SampleCode to facilitate such an interaction. My objective is to understand the limitations and capabilities of concurrent process interactions with an enclave.